# Microsoft Word 2007: top and bottom margins are gone?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007, margins

So take a look at the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, the top and bottom margins of the page are gone, but the left and right side still are still present. Any idea how to get them back? I'm using Microsoft Word 2007.

If I go into the page-setup, it says it has a top & bottom margin of 2,5 cm!

Answer (score 3):

Go with your cursor to the open space between the pages, and double click. [image: Screenshot]

Basically what happened is that your whitespace margins were hidden.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the margin to 1". This may fix your issue. 1" is the regular sire for the top and bottom margins.